# Using a variable in the x y sort

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have the following right now:

```
switch (Mysort)
{
    case "reqDate":
        lstDMV.Sort((x, y) => DateTime.Compare(x.RequestDate, y.RequestDate));
        break;
    case "notifDate":
        lstDMV.Sort((x, y) => DateTime.Compare(x.NotifDate, y.NotifDate));
        break;
    case "dueDate":
        lstDMV.Sort((x, y) => String.Compare(x.TargetDateShort, y.TargetDateShort));
        break;
    case "days":
        lstDMV.Sort((x, y) => x.DaysLapsed.CompareTo(y.DaysLapsed));
        break;
}
```

I want to get rid of the case statement and just do something like:

```
lstDMV.Sort((x, y) => String.Compare(x.MySort, y.MySort));
```

The case statement is HUGE and it will really cut down on readability. But because `MySort` is not contained in `lstDMV` it's not working. Is there another way I can substitute it in?

I will of course change the text to make sure `MySort` variable values match exactly to the `lstDMV` property names.

i've also tried the following with no luck :(

```
 if (sort != "")
            {
                string xsort, ysort;
                xsort = "x." + sort;
                ysort = "y." + sort;

                lstDMV.Sort((x, y) => String.Compare(xsort, ysort));
            }
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you've tagged this with LINQ when `List<T>.Sort` is *not* a LINQ method.

Comment: sorry, i removed it. when i was readying up on the lambda  operators it said that it's mostly used in LINQ :-/ newbie mistake

Comment: @TanyaXrum I don't understand: how would you remove the switch if some business rules are executed depending on the MySort value?

Comment: You could create a dictionary that maps strings to `Func<A, A, int>` (where `A` is the type of your `x` and `y`). That would remove the switch, though it would mean you'd have to fill the dictionary somewhere, which might be equally lengthy.

Comment: If you use a string to describe the sorting, you probably have to use a `switch` statement. You even have different methods of comparison. Maybe you should implement some `IComparer<T>` classes.

Comment: @ken2K the switch is really only there to know which value to sort by. i'm trying to do it by somehow passing that value into my function and getting rid of the switch all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dictionary with comparer Func's

```
    public class YourDataClass {
        public string RequestDate { get; set; }
        public string NotifDate { get; set; }
        .
        .
        .
    }

    public class Sorter<T> where T : YourDataClass {
        private Dictionary<string, Func<T, T, int>> actions =
            new Dictionary<string, Func<T, T, int>> {
                {"reqDate", (x, y) => String.Compare(x.RequestDate, y.RequestDate)},
                {"notifDate", (x, y) => String.Compare(x.NotifDate, y.NotifDate)}
            };

        public IEnumerable<T> Sort(IEnumerable<T> list, string howTo) {
            var items = list.ToArray();
            Array.Sort(items, (x, y) => actions[howTo](x, y));
            return items;
        }
    }

    public void Sample() {
        var list = new List<YourDataClass>();
        var sorter = new Sorter<YourDataClass>();
        var sortedItems = sorter.Sort(list, "reqDate");
    }
```

Comment: thanks! i almost got it ,except i'm trying to change yoru "sort" function to be of the same type as my data, but don't think i'm doing it right.... i don't know what to change the array.sort line with to make it work.... here is what i did: public List<DetailsModelView> Sort(List<DetailsModelView> list, string howTo)
        {
            List<DetailsModelView> items;
            Array.Sort(items, (x, y) => actions[howTo](x, y));
            return items;
        }

Comment: @TanyaXrum: Have a look at my answer with a dictionary of compare functions; it includes a line where I show how to invoke `Sort` (well, that of a list, as in your question, but it should be close enough).

Answer (score 2):

Well you could use reflection, assuming all your property types implement `IComparable`:

```
private class Test
{
    public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<Test>
    {
        new Test
        {
            RequestDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1),
            Name = "test"
        },
        new Test
        {
            RequestDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1),
            Name = "a_test"
        },
    };

    string mySort = "RequestDate";
    list.Sort((x, y) =>
        {
            // Gets the property that match the name of the variable
            var prop = typeof(Test).GetProperty(mySort);

            var leftVal = (IComparable)prop.GetValue(x, null);
            var rightVal = (IComparable)prop.GetValue(y, null);

            return leftVal.CompareTo(rightVal);
        });

    Console.Read();
}
```

I wouldn't recommend that, as even if there might be less code, it's less readable than the `switch` you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of Linq and Reflection, solving your issue in 3 lines of code. Here's the proof of concept:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
    public DateTime Since;
}

void Main()
{
    var tests = new Test[] {
        new Test(){Name="Dude", Age=23, Since = new DateTime(2000,2,3)},
        new Test(){Name="Guy", Age=29, Since = new DateTime(1999,3,4)},
        new Test(){Name="Man", Age=34, Since = new DateTime(2008,11,5)},
        new Test(){Name="Gentleman", Age=40, Since = new DateTime(2006,7,6)}
    };

    //up until here, all code was just test preparation. 
    //Here's the actual problem solving:

    string fieldToOrderBy = "Since"; //just replace this to change order
    FieldInfo myf = typeof(Test).GetField(fieldToOrderBy);
    tests.OrderBy(t=>myf.GetValue(t)).Dump(); 

    //the Dump() is because I ran this in LinqPad. 
    //Replace it by your favaorite way of inspecting an IEnumerable
}
```

Notice that the field information is obtained prior to the sorting, to try and improve performance.

I understand that your "SortBy" string is not the field name, but that's the easy part of the problem, which you can solve by using a dictionary to map the SortBy string to FieldName.

Comment: Thank you much! what is FieldInfo type?

Comment: @TanyaXrum It's a reflection class to aid us in getting information about a Class' field. Read on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `x` and `y` are of a type `A`, you could store the mapping in a dictionary:

```
var sortingFuncs = new Dictionary<string, Func<A, A, int>>();
```

The invocation of the sorting method will then not require a `switch` any more:

```
lstDMV.Sort(sortingFuncs[Mysort]);
```

Note, however, that you will end up with almost as much code someplace else, for the dictionary has to be populated at some point. An advantage is that this process could be more dynamic, for example, you could have plugins add their own sorting keys along with comparison functions.

On the other hand, there *might* be a very slight performance loss, as the compiler cannot possibly optimize the selection code based on the eligible values for `Mysort` any more.

Answer (score 0):

Create property selector:

```
Func<T, object> CreatePropSelector<T>(string propertyName)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var body = Expression.Convert(Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propertyName), typeof(object));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(body, parameter).Compile();
}
```

And use it to order sequence by property name:

```
lstDMV.OrderBy(CreatePropSelector<YourObjectType>(Mysort))
```

As with other Linq methods, it will not sort your list, but it will create enumerator:

```
Mysort = "RequestDate";
foreach(var item in lstDMV.OrderBy(CreatePropSelector<YourObjectType>(Mysort)))
     // sequence ordered by RequestDate property
```