# Code repository based on a condition

Tags: c#, .net

I have to write a bunch of little code snippets to perform string concats and transforms based on a numeric code. The codes will number in the hundreds and thousands.

Obviously I could build a giant switch statement to execute the code related to that numeric code. That seems unwieldy. It seems like I could create something like:

```
1001: if (x != null) {
    console.writeline("Not Null");
} else {
    console.writeline("Null");
}
```

Then whenever I need to run that code I can make a call to `1001`, and have the code executed.

Not sure if that makes sense, but I've never had to map a value to a piece of source code before.

Comment: This is essentially the same question as [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402930/using-a-variable-in-the-x-y-sort/14403421).

Comment: "number in the hundreds and thousands"... I smell something

Answer (score 2):

If, as an assumption, all your "snippets" use an single integer variable (yes, a fairly big assumption) you could use a dictionary to store them, something like this:

```
public class CodeRepo
{
  private Dictionary<int, Func<int, int>> snippets = new Dictionary<int, Func<int, int>>();

  public void RegisterCodeSnippet(int key, Func<int, int> code)
  {
    if (!snippets.ContainsKey(key))
      snippets.Add(key, code);  
  }

  public Func<int, int> GetCodeSnippet(int key)
  {
    if (snippets.ContainsKey(key))
      return snippets[key];
    return null;
  }

  public IEnumerable<int> RunAllSnippets(int parameter)
  {
    foreach (var item in snippets)
      yield return item.Value(parameter);
  }
}
```

You could use that repository like:

```
CodeRepo repo = new CodeRepo();
repo.RegisterCodeSnippet(1, x => x); //identity function;
repo.RegisterCodeSnippet(2, x => x * x);//x squared
repo.RegisterCodeSnippet(3, x => Math.Sign(x));//sign of x
// etc...

var square = repo.GetCodeSnippet(2);
Console.WriteLine(square(7)); //writes 49

//runs all snippets in order, produces 3, 9, 1
foreach (int result in repo.RunAllSnippets(3))
{
  Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `List<Action>` and assign each snippet in order, then you could call them using the list index:

```
public List<Action> Actions {get;set;}

public void CreateActions()
{
  Action action0000 = () => {//code snippet here};

  Actions.Add(action0000);

  //.. etc etc etc

}
```

Then when calling it:

```
public void CallAction(int code)
{
    Actions[code]();
}
```

Comment: Or you can use Func if you want to return values.

Comment: You might want to use a dictionary object to have the lookup instead of a list.  With the list object, you would have to know the index of the action or func.

Comment: @user959729: I think HighCore assumes the numeric code matches the index. No knowing of any additional index required.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative would be reflection (MethodBase.Invoke).  This allows your snippets to be unit-testable.  I didn't test it myself, but it could look something like:

```
class MyClass
{
    public void Fn100() {...}
    public void Fn101() {...}
    public void Fn102() {...}
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ExecFnNumber("100");
        ExecFnNumber("105");
    }

    public static void ExecFnNumber(string num)
    {
        // can probably optimize by not instantiating
        // myType, myTypeObject every time.
        Type myType = typeof(MyClass);

        // create an instance
        var myTypeObject = new MyClass();

        // call method without params
        MethodInfo method = myType.GetMethod("Fn" + num);
        method.Invoke(myTypeObject, new object[]{});
    }
}
```

See also MSDN - [MethodBase.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx)